# How python interpreter determine the type of variable at runtime?

Tags: python

I just want to know how python's **(python 2.7)** interpreter is find the type of variable. Like How python Dynamic Type Behaviour internally works.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ neelabhsingh$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 14:05:02)
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(str1)
<type 'str'>
>>> testFloat = 45.67
>>> type(testFloat)
<type 'float'>
```

Comment: Which particular implementation? CPython 2.7 or 3.4? Or others; PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc?

Comment: @PeterWood, Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 4):

In CPython 2.7 (i.e. the C language implementation of Python), there is a [`PyObject` type](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject). There is also a [`PyObject_Type`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Type) function which accesses the type stored in the `PyObject` i.e. the object carries around type information with it.